# Geth Node as Web3 Provider: Impact of Multiple Client Connections

Tags: go-ethereum, web3-providers, server-side

Related to this question ([restricting access to Geth node](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/30357/restricted-access-authentication-for-a-remote-geth-node)), if I have a remote geth node and several clients connecting to it as a web3 provider `const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://myGethNode'));`, will there be any performance impact from more and more clients connecting to it?

Will an increasing number of client connections result in a material increase in use of server resources or potentially even increase the risk of server error/faults?

How many clients can a single geth node support before having an adverse impact on the server?