# Help with setting up Private POA(Clique) Ethereum Network

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain, memory, poa, clique

Geth Version : 1.8.12-stable-37685930

Testing on Amazon EC2 t2.large(8GB RAM) machine with Ubuntu 16.04 running.

I am in need of setting up a multi node private POA(Clique) ethereum network. Initially I am testing with setting up a single node network with two accounts. While setting up a genesis block through puppeth, I am allocating 1 account as sealer and 1 account as one to be funded with ethers).
I am able to setup a network once but and also deploy a contract on it but,

There are mainly two errors that are bothering me.

1) **The balance of account which I am funding in the genesis.json becomes 0** once blockchain is made running for a day. Once this happens my blockchain becomes useless as there is no way I can obtain balance in accounts in POA.

2) **My geth crashes after running for a day with this error**.

```
fatal error: runtime: out of memory

runtime stack:
runtime.throw(0xf49da4, 0x16)
    /usr/lib/go-1.10/src/runtime/panic.go:619 +0x81
runtime.sysMap(0xc608600000, 0x10000000, 0x0, 0x1b547d8)
......................................
```

It continues

**This is the genesis block that gets generated through puppeth**

```
{
  "config": {
    "chainId": 260192,
    "homesteadBlock": 1,
    "eip150Block": 2,
    "eip150Hash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
    "eip155Block": 3,
    "eip158Block": 3,
    "byzantiumBlock": 4,
    "clique": {
      "period": 5,
      "epoch": 30000
    }
  },
  "nonce": "0x0",
  "timestamp": "0x5b3e76d1",
  "extraData": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000044056b6d00af3af4319dbdfb4b18e4e6a039dfc0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "gasLimit": "0x47b760",
  "difficulty": "0x1",
  "mixHash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "coinbase": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "alloc": {
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000001": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000002": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000003": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000004": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000005": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000006": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000007": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000008": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000009": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000000a": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000000b": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000000c": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000000d": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000000e": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000000f": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000010": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000011": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000012": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000013": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000014": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000015": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000016": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000017": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000018": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000019": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000001a": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000001b": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000001c": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000001d": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000001e": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000001f": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000020": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000021": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000022": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000023": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000024": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000025": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000026": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000027": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000028": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000029": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000002a": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000002b": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000002c": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000002d": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000002e": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000002f": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000030": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000031": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000032": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000033": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000034": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000035": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000036": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000037": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000038": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000039": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000003a": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000003b": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000003c": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000003d": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000003e": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000003f": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000040": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000041": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000042": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000043": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000044": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000045": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000046": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000047": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000048": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000049": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000004a": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000004b": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000004c": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000004d": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000004e": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000004f": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000050": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000051": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000052": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000053": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000054": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000055": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000056": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000057": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000058": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000059": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000005a": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000005b": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000005c": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000005d": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000005e": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000005f": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000060": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000061": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000062": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000063": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000064": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000065": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000066": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000067": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000068": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000069": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000006a": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000006b": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000006c": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000006d": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000006e": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000006f": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000070": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000071": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000072": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000073": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000074": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000075": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000076": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000077": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000078": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000079": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000007a": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000007b": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000007c": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000007d": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000007e": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000007f": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000080": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000081": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000082": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000083": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000084": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000085": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000086": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000087": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000088": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000089": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000008a": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000008b": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000008c": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000008d": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000008e": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000008f": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000090": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000091": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000092": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000093": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000094": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000095": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000096": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000097": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000098": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000099": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000009a": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000009b": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000009c": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000009d": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000009e": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000009f": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000a0": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000a1": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000a2": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000a3": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000a4": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000a5": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000a6": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000a7": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000a8": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000a9": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000aa": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000ab": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000ac": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000ad": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000ae": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000af": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000b0": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000b1": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000b2": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000b3": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000b4": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000b5": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000b6": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000b7": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000b8": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000b9": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000ba": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000bb": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000bc": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000bd": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000be": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000bf": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000c0": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000c1": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000c2": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000c3": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000c4": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000c5": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000c6": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000c7": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000c8": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000c9": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000ca": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000cb": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000cc": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000cd": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000ce": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000cf": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000d0": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000d1": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000d2": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000d3": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000d4": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000d5": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000d6": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000d7": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000d8": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000d9": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000da": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000db": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000dc": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000dd": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000de": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000df": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000e0": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000e1": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000e2": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000e3": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000e4": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000e5": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000e6": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000e7": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000e8": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000e9": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000ea": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000eb": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000ec": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000ed": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000ee": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000ef": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000f0": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000f1": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000f2": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000f3": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000f4": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000f5": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000f6": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000f7": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000f8": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000f9": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000fa": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000fb": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000fc": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000fd": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000fe": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "00000000000000000000000000000000000000ff": {
      "balance": "0x1"
    },
    "aa4e65599a6dd0718a0327e2011ef8edfd385c73": {
      "balance": "0x200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
    }
  },
  "number": "0x0",
  "gasUsed": "0x0",
  "parentHash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
}
```

**These are the steps I am following for network creation**

```
mkdir testNet
cd testNet
geth --datadir node1/ account new

<Address1>

geth --datadir node1/ account new

<Address2>

echo "pwd" > node1/password.txt
```

puppeth

```
Protocol : POA(Clique)
Block Creation Time: 5sec
Address1 as sealer
Address2 as account to be funded with ethers
Network Id : 260192
```

"Exporting the genesis file as genesis.json"

```
geth --datadir node1/ init genesis.json

nohup geth --networkid 260192 --datadir node1/ --nodiscover --unlock <Address1> --password node1/password.txt --rpc --rpcaddr 0.0.0.0 --rpcapi eth,net,web3,personal --rpccorsdomain "*" --mine &

cd testChain/node1
geth attach geth.ipc

personal.unlockAccount(<Address2>,"pwd",0)

exit
```

Attaching the geth log file.

[nohup.txt](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/files/2179477/nohup.txt)

Answer (score 1):

I think someone have access to your node and spam it with transaction to his address from your unlocked accounts. This empties your balance and spam so much your node with tx that it runs out of memory.

The accounts spamming your node are :

```
0x7097f41F1C1847D52407C629d0E0ae0fDD24fd58
0x6e4Cc3e76765bdc711cc7b5CbfC5bBFe473B192E
0x8652328B96Ff12B20de5fDc67b67812E2b64e2A6
```

and it starts at the line 91425 of your log file.

Their goal is to find a main net node with unlocked accounts and stole all their funds.

You need to secure the rpc connection to your node if you expose "personal". For example use nginx with a basic auth. See this [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-password-authentication-with-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04) or this question [Restricted Access / Authentication for a Remote Geth Node](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/30357/restricted-access-authentication-for-a-remote-geth-node).